# Axios authentifaction request fails to send header to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, authentication, spring-security, axios

I am trying to implement Authorization with Axios on RN part and send the token to Spring Boot backend. I've tried to do it before with simple sending email and password as parameters of GET request and it worked fine, but now when I'am trying to send basic headers with btoa to backend part, it keeps receiving null value.
My React Native part:

```
  login(user) {   
  const headers = {
  authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(user.email + ':' + user.password)
  };

return axios.get(API_URL + 'login', {headers: headers})
.then(response => {
console.log('function called')
```

And my Controller on Spring Boot:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> login(Principal principal) {
    if(principal == null){
        //logout will also use here so we should return ok http status.
        return (ResponseEntity<?>) ResponseEntity.badRequest();
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal;
```

When I debug the controller, I see that my method parameter principle is receiving null. 
I guess the issue might be somewhere either in the header or Controller parameter, but have real idea.

Answer (score 0):

Headers should be:

```
{
  headers: {
     "Authorization": "Basic "...
  }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
{
  auth: {
     username: "",
     password: ""
  }
}
```

Which will add the basic auth header for you

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config for reference